# react leaflet loading 1000 markers

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

is there a better way to load 1000 markers to the react leaflet map. it takes a while

```
  useEffect(() => {
   //get Marker coordinates from db
     setMarkerData(data)
  }, []);

  <Map
        center={[0,0]}
        maxZoom={18} //shows map
        minZoom={3}
        id="map"
        zoomControl={false}
        ref={(e) => {
          setMapInstance(e);
        }}>
     <MarkerClusterGroup>
      {MarkerData.map((marker, index) => {
            const post = [marker.latitude, marker.longitude];
            return (
              <Marker
                key={index}
                position={post}
                data={marker}
                <Popup>
                  <strong>{marker.title}</strong>
                </Popup>
              </Marker>
```

I am trying to get display the markers on the map with the coordinates fetched from the database. Would it be better to periodically fetch a number of markers at X interval?

Comment: Looks like a known issue of react-leaflet-markercluster when Markers are added after initial rendering: https://github.com/yuzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster/issues/76

Comment: oh is there anythin i can do for now?

Comment: There are at least 2 workarounds mentioned in that issue. Have you tried them?

Comment: is the one with  chunkedLoading={true} chunkInterval={100} in MarkerClusterGroup

Comment: I have the exact same problem except without cluster group, did you figure out a way to load or preload the markers?